# Multi-line label of unlimited size with the text top-aligned?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I haven't been able to figure it out and most of the techniques coming up in Google have been deprecated:

I want to have a multi-line label of unlimited size with the text top-aligned.

How do I do it?

Comment: Set the number of lines to 0

Comment: I already did (and set Line Breaks to Word Wrap), but the label itself is constrained to a static size in the display. Also, I tried stretching to a taller static size, but then the text is aligned in the middle vertically (and still doesn't scroll when there's overflow). Even then, the label isn't stretching to fit different screen sizes.

Comment: Did you add constraints in the InterfaceBuilder to it?
Add constraints to pin to the top, left and right to the superview - then the label will grow in it's height. Without constraints it will just have the "default" dragged size I guess in the InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: What do you mean by unlimited size? Unlimited width or unlimited height? You can't have both because if there is unlimited width then the text would never go into another line.

Comment: "What do you mean by unlimited size?" - roughly the width of the phone, vertical scrollbars when the label overflows the view.

Comment: Christian, I'll try to figure that out and give it a whirl.

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler - did you want to put that in the form of an answer? It worked (after I figured out the proper place to add constraints).

Comment: @Colin I entered an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add constraints in your Interface Builder or in code, the view will use it's "default" size in the Interface Builder.

Set the numberOfLines of the label to 0.
Pin constraints in your Interface Builder from the label's top to it's superview + left and right of the label to it's superview.

Then the label grows with it's content as long as needed. You can also add a bottom constraint to the label with a >= X value which limits the label also in it's height when you want to have a max height.